# Analytically solvable examples of quantal response equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, behavioral-economics

I have been reading up on [quantal response equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantal_response_equilibrium) and am looking for some simple examples which can be solved analytically (in order to gain some intuition about how exactly QRE works). To be more concrete, I am willing to consider the logit version of the quantal response function
$$ \text{P(choose A)} = \frac{\text{exp}(\lambda\text{(expected payoff from A)}}{\sum_X\text{exp}(\lambda\text{(expected payoff from X)}}$$

and (somewhat) happy to further impose $\lambda = 1$ if this makes finding the equilibrium easier.

Does anyone have any ideas? Examples where QRE contrasts starkly with Nash equilibrium would be especially appreciated.

Comment: How about the example I have in this answer:https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/20531/42?

Comment: Thanks for linking. Just to clarify, should I be able to find explicit expressions for $p$ and $q$ in your example? (Possibly after imposing $\lambda = 1$)

Comment: NB I was not able to do this (I suspect that this is a general feature of these systems of exponential equations)

Comment: Aren't equations 1 and 2 there expressions of p and q (after setting lambda=1)? Because of quantal *reponse*, p and q must be functions of each other.

Comment: Yes, I was just saying that I couldn't combine them to find *explicit* expressions for $p$ and $q$, i.e. find analytical solutions for $p$ and $q$. You are of course correct that these equations *implicitly* define $p$ and $q$.